# I want to create a regression model by transfer learning, but I get an error

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

My goal is to create a model that predicts two-numbers from one-image.
So I'm trying to implement transfer learning. However, I got an error.

The model implementation is as follows.

```
# input img shape : (100,100,3)
base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False, input_shape=(100,100,3)) 

x = base.output
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output1 = Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)
output2 = Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base.input,outputs=[output1,output2])
model.compile(optimizer ='adam',loss = 'mse', metrics = ['mae'])

# All data is stored in the list
history = model.fit([np.array(trainIMG)],[np.array(trainVal1),np.array(trainVal2)],
                    epochs=100,batch_size=8,
                    validation_data=([np.array(TestIMG)],[np.array(testVal1),np.array(testVal2)]))
```

Error↓

```
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.tensordot), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(512, 512) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.nn.bias_add), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.tensordot_1), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(512, 1) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.nn.bias_add_1), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.tensordot_2), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'dense_2/kernel:0' shape=(512, 1) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.nn.bias_add_2), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'dense_2/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.

2021-06-26 19:23:01.524564: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
Epoch 1/100
2021-06-26 19:23:09.797624: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-06-26 19:23:10.091894: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:359] Loaded cuDNN version 8200
2021-06-26 19:23:10.416480: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-06-26 19:23:10.669945: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-06-26 19:23:11.181791: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1755] Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
2021-06-26 19:23:11.182116: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1755] Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/userA/OneDrive/doc/StudyAI/CNN.py", line 164, in <module>
    history = model.fit([np.array(PPG_train)],[np.array(S_IBP_train),np.array(D_IBP_train)],
  File "C:\Users\userA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1158, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\userA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\userA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 950, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\userA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3023, in __call__
    return graph_function._call_flat(
  File "C:\Users\userA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1960, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "C:\Users\userA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 591, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "C:\Users\userA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
         [[node sub (defined at C:\Users\userA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py:1301) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2222]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sub:
 model/tf.nn.relu_1/Relu (defined at C:\Users\userA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py:551)
 ExpandDims (defined at C:\Users\userA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py:1414)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because the loss function you have specified does not match with the output shape. The outputs shapes are `(3,3,1)` (use `model.summary()` to see), so you can not specify a `mse` loss function for them. For feeding data through dense layers, first flatten them.

So, you should first flatten the data before your first dense layer like this:

```
x = base.output
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)       # Add this line
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output1 = Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)
output2 = Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base.input,outputs=[output1,output2])
model.compile(optimizer ='adam',loss = 'mse', metrics = ['mae'])
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved this problem.
I decided to get into the habit of observing the model with model.summary()